# Prove the recursive enumerability of the class of NP-hard context-free languages

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

I was asked to prove that the next language is recursive enumerable :

$$L= \{ \langle G \rangle \mid SAT<L(G) \} $$

where $G$ is a context free grammar and there is a polynomial reduction from the SAT problem to the language that's accepted by $G$.

I can't seem to understand why this problem is in RE. Isn't determining whether a word is accepted by a certain CFG done in a polynomial time? What am I missing here?

Comment: First, note that P is a subset of RE. Second, there is no obvious connection between the fact that the word problem for CFGs has an efficient solution and the problem at hand. I suggest reviewing the definitions involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should distinguish between two cases. If $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ then $L(G)$ cannot be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard since $L(G) \in \mathsf{P}$. In this case, $L = \emptyset$.

Conversely, if $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$, then all non-trivial languages in $\mathsf{P}$ are $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. In this case, $L = \{ \langle G \rangle : L(G) \neq \emptyset, \Sigma^* \}$. It is possible to decide whether $L(G) \neq \emptyset$, and the problem of determining whether $L(G) \neq \Sigma^*$ is clearly r.e. (in fact, it is $\Sigma_1$-complete), and so $L$ is r.e. (in fact, $\Sigma_1$-complete).

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much for the clearness! I thought that whenever I have to approach questions like these I have to keep in mind that P is always not equal to NP, my bad!

Comment: So if I'm asked what is the smallest class that this language is in then RE it is?

Comment: The smallest class that contains this language is clearly $\{L\}$.